# How to retrieve key value to listview from firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I have saved date as the key. Now I want to retrieve the dates to the list view. I am aware of how to retrieve the child value to the listview but not sure how to do the same for key values. Below is the code i am using:

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(savedCollname).
child("Students").child(userId).child("Lectures").child(post_key);

FirebaseListOptions<String> options = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<String>()
.setLayout(R.layout.subject_list_heading)

.setQuery(databaseReference, String.class)
.build();

adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(options) {


@Override
protected void populateView(View v, String model, int position) {

TextView subject_name = v.findViewById(R.id.tv_sub_heading);
subject_name.setText(model);



}
};

list_of_date.setAdapter(adapter);
```

My app crashes with the error: `Failed to convert value of type java.util.Hashmap to String`

JSON object of database:

```
{
  "-LHSdSCzD_tZhzqvSOw_" : {
    "17-7-2018" : {
      "Absent" : "0",
      "Present" : "1",
      "Total_Lectures" : "1"
    },
      "18-7-2018" : {
      "Absent" : "0",
      "Present" : "1",
      "Total_Lectures" : "1"
    }
}
```

I want to retrieve the dates ie the node to the listview.
If there is any other way please do mention. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void populateView(View v, String model, int position) {
    adapter.getRef(position).getKey();
    //Use this method to get the key.

}
```

Comment: The app is still crashing giving the same error as above.